When the path of lib contains @, the type of the submodule cannot be obtained in monaco-editor, how to solve this problem?

open this monaco-editor playground
hover Typography and click to peek definition, and then you can't see OriginTypography type.


If rename @scope/myLib to myLib, then it can get type when peek definition, so I think there must be some problems when use addExtraLib to add some lib that its path has @, most of lib may have scope, so @ can't be avoided.

